# Codeigniter admin application in subfolder shows 404 error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

i have the following problem..

I've created themain codeigniter website which is located in *sub.domain.com* and i've also created another codeigniter application (the admin) in *sub.domain.com/admin*..

*Note that i 'm not using HMVC model, in case someone mentions it...

The thing is that when i'm trying to access the /admin url i get a error 404 redirect problem.

Here are my main files and some extra things i shall mention:

***.htaccess*** file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Indexes default
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /admin
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

My ***routes.php*** file:

```
/**
* Users login - logout
*/
$route['login'] = 'users/users/login';
$route['logout'] = 'users/users/logout'; //Controller located in subfolder

$route['users'] = 'users/users';
$route['users/(:any)'] = 'users/users/$1';
/**
* Redirect any URI after default url
*/
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'pages/$1';

/**
* Other routes
*/
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I also have this in my ***header.php*** file in which i redirect the user in login if not logged in etc.. etc..

```
if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() && $this->uri->segment(1) !== 'login') {              
    redirect('login');
} elseif( $this->ion_auth->logged_in() && !$this->ion_auth->is_admin($this->ion_auth->get_user_id()) ){
    redirect('logout');
}
```

The ***application/controllers*** structure is like:

```
Controllers
-Customers
--Customers.php
-Users
--Users.php
-Pages.php
etc..etc..
```

I've tried everything (.htaccess, RewriteBase /admin etc..) but still nothing works..

Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: You wrote that you have the main application and another application - this can be done in different ways, and the answer depends on it.
Please, show your folder and files structure on upper level (when folders application, system, www, e.t.c). Folder 'admin' = 'application' folder, other 'project' or folder/controller in main application?

Comment: @ElenaVasilenko
Under sub.domain.com the structure is: (admin, application, assets, system, .htaccess, etc.. etc..) and under sub.domain.com/admin the structure is: (application, assets, system, .htaccess etc.. etc..) 
If that's what you mean!

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. My decision below in the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**.htaccess in main application:**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)admin(.*)$ /admin/index.php$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess in /admin:**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) /admin/index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nope. Still the same.. If it helps as i've checked the logs i see this: 
**ERROR - 2019-07-16 22:33:01 --> 404 Page Not Found: Users/users**

Moreover if i remove the script from the header.php it kinda works.. But i still can't go to the controllers that are located in subfolders..
I've also tried different name for the parent folder where e.g.: users.php is located.. Still nothing..

Comment: @Citer Try to rename your controllers folder and subfolders to lowercase, only folder and subfolders:
`controllers
-customers
--Customers.php
-users
--Users.php
-Pages.php
etc..etc..`